# iOS dismiss keyboard on webview for specific UITextField

Tags: html, objective-c, webview

I have a simple Webview (UIWebViewController) in Objective-C which open my website.
Works perfectly, but on my website I have a Textfield (named ID=eventdatetime) with a datepicker (jquery) and everytimes I choose this textfield, the iOS keyboard comes up. Is there a way to dismiss the keyboard only for this textfield? The other textfields should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to to textfield(named ID=eventdatetime)

```
[eventdatetimeTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

-(void)textFieldDidChange
{
  [eventdatetimeTextField resignFirstResponder]; 
}
```

Comment: @ hesje try this

Comment: I forgot a important information: the Textfield eventdatetime is a HTML imput textfield.